# Get Product Id On Product Page

Tags: magento2, catalog, magento2.3

How can i get product id on product page without registry? Such as class registry is deprecated in magento 2.3

Comment: can you post your code? what di you try,? you can use ProductRepository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a view model.

Vinal kopp, write a blog where he has to create a custom registry but note that registry, not *Magento generic registry like global variable*.

- `The product is loaded by
  \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product::initProduct. This method dispatches
  the event catalog_controller_product_init_after.`
- `In the event observer RegisterCurrentProductObserver the product is
  set on a shared instance of the class
  \VinaiKopp\CurrentProductExample\Registry\CurrentProduct.`
- `A new template block is added to the product detail page with layout
  XML. In the XML the block is configured to receive a view model, an
  instance of the class
  \VinaiKopp\CurrentProductExample\ViewModel\CurrentProductExampleViewModel`.
- `The view model uses the shared Registry\CurrentProduct instance to
  retrieve the current product. This makes it a registry but without
  the downsides of the global core registry.`
- `The template retrieves the view model from the block and renders the
  required product value`

More detail at https://github.com/Vinai/module-current-product-example

Comment: It's not proper for me, but it is the best decision among the proposed.

Comment: Credit goes to vinai koop

Answer (score 3):

I have created a demo extension for you.

Link >> https://github.com/magento1993/ProductId

[image]

Comment: You are right, but, you created class and extends it from `AbstractProduct` that is using registry

Comment: extension updated plz check again, this time I am using product view block in the layout

Comment: Yes, but block you are using, use registry to get a product.